# React Native: ZIndex with dynamic views

Tags: css, react-native, z-index, styling

I'm new to React Native and trying to build an app in which I present a tiled overview to my user. I construct this tiled overview with a FlatList with 3 columns. I need to make it look like all items are hanging on a rope that runs vertically behind the tiles I have, and I'm trying to achieve this by setting the Z-Index of my "item" view to 1000 and the zIndex of my "rope" view to 1. See the example below:

[image]

the code of my cell looks like this:

```
export default class ItemButton extends Component {

  //

render() {
    const { item, style, onPress } = this.props
    console.log('style for itemButton: ', style)
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={style} onPress={onPress}>
            <Image style={{zIndex:1000, width: style.width, height: style.height}} resizeMode={'contain'} source={require('../Artwork/Items/cta-enter.png')}></Image>
            <Image style={{top: -Math.abs(style.height + 100), height: 200, width: 30, zIndex:1, alignSelf: 'center'}} source={require('../Artwork/Items/rope.png')} resizeMode={'contain'}></Image>
        </TouchableOpacity>        
    );
  }
}
```

And I implement it in my FlatList as follows:

```
renderCollectionItem(item) {
    return <ItemButton item={item} style={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={() => this.collectionItemPressed(item)} />
  }

render() {
return (
   <FlatList
  style={{width: collectionViewWidth, flexDirection: 'row', overflow: 'visible', top: this.props.style.top}}
  contentContainerStyle={[{left: this.props.horizontalSpacing / 2}, internalStyles.collectionViewContentStyle]}
  data = { this.convertToIndexed(this.props.items) }
  renderItem = {({item}) => (
    this.renderCollectionItem(item[0])
  )}
  numColumns={(3)}
  key={(Helpers.isPortrait() ? this.state.portraitRowSize : this.state.landscapeRowSize)}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
);
}
```

However, this does not work as React-Native always places views that are rendered later at a higher Z-Index.

**Question:**
How should I configure my FlatList to get the result I need as shown in the picture above?

Comment: can show some code, so that we can take a closer look at your implementation?

Comment: @HaiderAli I just updated my question with the code in my cell, which is where I add the rope

Comment: I have checked out your implementation and it looks fine https://snack.expo.io/@hiaiderali101/honest-almond, I think you need to check that how are you implementing this on FlatList. ps giving zIndex: 1 and -1 will also work in your case

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the effort. Your code example works because the order of rendering. In my flatlist, I render all elements after each other which automatically gives them a higher Z-Index. This is the problem I'm trying to get an answer on with this question, not just regular Z-Index configuration

Comment: Can you also show your FlatList implementation?

Comment: Done! it's just a basic flatlist implementation.

Answer (score -1):

unfortunately react-native doesn't support z-index .. 
i faced the same problem with a dynamic component , 
the solution was to use Elevation property in the style of both element here is the trick :

- give the element you want to be on the top higher elevation say 15.
- give the other element you want to be bottom of the other element lower Elevation say 5 . 
  the result will be exactly what you want ..